# AWS: Unable to use the "dynamodb:LeadingKeys" condition to control access to a GSI in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have been referring to these blog articles from AWS to implement tenant data isolation in DynamoDB. I came up with the below IAM policy which is attached to the IAM Role going to be used to access the table I've created in DynamoDB.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "tenant/t001/product/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:table/<TABLE-NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "tenant/t001/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:table/<TABLE-NAME>/index/<INDEX-NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this, I was **denied access** to perform PutItem on the table when the value I passed for the Partition Key (PartKey1) of the table's Primary Key is NOT following the pattern `tenant/t001/product/*`. For example, I was denied access when I passed `tenant/t002/product/p001` to PartKey1 as expected. Because I'm giving `t002` as the tenant id, which should have been `t001` to successfully perform PutItem.

But, it was not the same with the GSI. It simply accepts any value I pass into the Partition Key of the GSI (PartKey2).

Then I changed the `dynamodb:PutItem` action to `dynamodb:Query` ONLY in the second statement. So the new inline policy would look like this.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "tenant/t001/product/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:table/<TABLE-NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "tenant/t001/*"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Action": "dynamodb:Query",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:table/<TABLE-NAME>/index/<INDEX-NAME>",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this change, I was denied access (as expected) when I tried to query the GSI with a value that doesn't follow the pattern `tenant/t001/*`, for example, `tenant/t002/product`.

I couldn't think of any reason why would AWS allow the use of `dynamodb:LeadingKeys` (for a GSI) in conditions when it is `dynamodb:Query` but not with `dynamodb:PutItem`. Because why would we go into trouble of isolating tenant data in Query time, when we cannot isolate them during the insertion?

Am I missing something here?

**AWS blog articles, documentations:**

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-secure-your-saas-tenant-data-in-dynamodb-with-abac-and-client-side-encryption/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-pooled-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-dynamodb/

Answer (score 1):

You can't `PutItem` to GSI (or LSI) ...

So in your original policy

```
"Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
"Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT-NUMBER>:table/<TABLE-NAME>/index/<INDEX-NAME>",
"Effect": "Allow"
```

Has zero effect...